# BLE GATT upload data - Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

Trying to connect to BLE device(GATT Server) Using Samsung Galaxy S4, 
I succeeded to connect to device and got heartbeat.

now I need to send 1280 bytes as 16 chunks of 80 bytes. the Device after receiving those 16 chunks should reply with 16 upload status,

what I get is only one upload status for one of the chunks (not specific one , randomly)

I tried to change the sending interval by (this.wait, Thread.sleep..) with many values , 
without any good result.

Similar application with Objective-c (iPhone ) works fine with device  :(

**
I thought it might be related to the
Any hints about the issue ? 
or a way to manage  transmission rate (interval)**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < chunkToUpload; ++i) {
                sendNthModeData(i);
                try {   
                    //this.wait(100);
                    Thread.sleep(30,1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for `onCharacteristicWrite` to be called in the `BluetoothGattCallback` before you can send the next bit of data, otherwise the other data will get dropped on the ground. So in your override of `onCharacteristicWrite`, if you have more to write then spin up a Runnable for that write.